# Tailwind CSS divs disappear without content. Advice no how make divs fit to screen better?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```js
 function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-col ">
        <div className="bg-blue-400 h-16"></div>
        <div className="flex flex-row items-stretch h-max ">   
          <div className ="basis-3/4 bg-red-600"><Mainscreen/></div>
          <div className= "basis-1/4 bg-black text-white" ><Mainscreen/></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  );
}
```

I am trying to make a UI where there is a top banner, and then a section at the bottom which fits the max size of the screen, and will scroll with enough content. I am running into the problem that without any content, the flex boxes will not even display at all. The only way that I can get them to show a proper height is if I hardcode the height.

[This is how I would like the page to look, without resorting to using h-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLlre.png)

Comment: The image is not matching with the specification you asked , there's no bottom section , can you be more descriptive or add proper image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `h-full`. This will allow you take the space that the content have. You can see below example for that.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <div class="h-16 bg-blue-400"></div>
  <div class="flex flex-row items-stretch">
    <div class="h-full basis-3/4 bg-red-200">
      <section class="body-font relative text-gray-600">
        <div class="container mx-auto px-5 py-24">
          <div class="mb-12 flex w-full flex-col text-center">
            <h1 class="title-font mb-4 text-2xl font-medium text-gray-900 sm:text-3xl">Contact Us</h1>
            <p class="mx-auto text-base leading-relaxed lg:w-2/3">Whatever cardigan tote bag tumblr hexagon brooklyn asymmetrical gentrify.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mx-auto md:w-2/3 lg:w-1/2">
            <div class="-m-2 flex flex-wrap">
              <div class="w-1/2 p-2">
                <div class="relative">
                  <label for="name" class="text-sm leading-7 text-gray-600">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="w-full rounded border border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 bg-opacity-50 py-1 px-3 text-base leading-8 text-gray-700 outline-none transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out focus:border-indigo-500 focus:bg-white focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-200" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-1/2 p-2">
                <div class="relative">
                  <label for="email" class="text-sm leading-7 text-gray-600">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="w-full rounded border border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 bg-opacity-50 py-1 px-3 text-base leading-8 text-gray-700 outline-none transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out focus:border-indigo-500 focus:bg-white focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-200" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-full p-2">
                <div class="relative">
                  <label for="message" class="text-sm leading-7 text-gray-600">Message</label>
                  <textarea id="message" name="message" class="h-32 w-full resize-none rounded border border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 bg-opacity-50 py-1 px-3 text-base leading-6 text-gray-700 outline-none transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out focus:border-indigo-500 focus:bg-white focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-200"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-full p-2">
                <button class="mx-auto flex rounded border-0 bg-indigo-500 py-2 px-8 text-lg text-white hover:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none">Button</button>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-8 w-full border-t border-gray-200 p-2 pt-8 text-center">
                <a class="text-indigo-500">example@email.com</a>
                <p class="my-5 leading-normal">49 Smith St. <br />Saint Cloud, MN 56301</p>
                <span class="inline-flex">
                  <a class="text-gray-500">
                    <svg fill="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path d="M18 2h-3a5 5 0 00-5 5v3H7v4h3v8h4v-8h3l1-4h-4V7a1 1 0 011-1h3z"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                  <a class="ml-4 text-gray-500">
                    <svg fill="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path d="M23 3a10.9 10.9 0 01-3.14 1.53 4.48 4.48 0 00-7.86 3v1A10.66 10.66 0 013 4s-4 9 5 13a11.64 11.64 0 01-7 2c9 5 20 0 20-11.5a4.5 4.5 0 00-.08-.83A7.72 7.72 0 0023 3z"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                  <a class="ml-4 text-gray-500">
                    <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <rect width="20" height="20" x="2" y="2" rx="5" ry="5"></rect>
                      <path d="M16 11.37A4 4 0 1112.63 8 4 4 0 0116 11.37zm1.5-4.87h.01"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                  <a class="ml-4 text-gray-500">
                    <svg fill="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path d="M21 11.5a8.38 8.38 0 01-.9 3.8 8.5 8.5 0 01-7.6 4.7 8.38 8.38 0 01-3.8-.9L3 21l1.9-5.7a8.38 8.38 0 01-.9-3.8 8.5 8.5 0 014.7-7.6 8.38 8.38 0 013.8-.9h.5a8.48 8.48 0 018 8v.5z"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="h-full basis-1/4 bg-black text-white">
      <section class="body-font text-gray-600">
        <div class="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap px-5 py-24">
          <div class="flex w-full flex-wrap">
            <div class="md:w-1/2 md:py-6 md:pr-10 lg:w-2/5">
              <div class="relative flex pb-12">
                <div class="absolute inset-0 flex h-full w-10 items-center justify-center">
                  <div class="pointer-events-none h-full w-1 bg-gray-200"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="relative z-10 inline-flex h-10 w-10 flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-indigo-500 text-white">
                  <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M12 22s8-4 8-10V5l-8-3-8 3v7c0 6 8 10 8 10z"></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-grow pl-4">
                  <h2 class="title-font mb-1 text-sm font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-900">STEP 1</h2>
                  <p class="leading-relaxed">VHS cornhole pop-up, try-hard 8-bit iceland helvetica. Kinfolk bespoke try-hard cliche palo santo offal.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="relative flex pb-12">
                <div class="absolute inset-0 flex h-full w-10 items-center justify-center">
                  <div class="pointer-events-none h-full w-1 bg-gray-200"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="relative z-10 inline-flex h-10 w-10 flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-indigo-500 text-white">
                  <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M22 12h-4l-3 9L9 3l-3 9H2"></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-grow pl-4">
                  <h2 class="title-font mb-1 text-sm font-medium tracking-wider text-gray-900">STEP 2</h2>
                  <p class="leading-relaxed">Vice migas literally kitsch +1 pok pok. Truffaut hot chicken slow-carb health goth, vape typewriter.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However you can use the `h-screen` to use the full space irrespective of the length of the content .